# JPA with Specification - How to filter an entity by a child collection content?

Tags: java, jpa, filter, specifications

I'm facing a problem to filter an entity by a value from a child that is in a list.
Ex:

```
public class Father(){
  private String name;
  private Set<Child> childs;
}
public class Child(){
  private String name;
  private Integer age;
  private School school;
}
public class School(){
  private String name;
}
```

I'd like to filter all father's that has a child in school X.

This is what I did, but is not working properly:

```
 Specification specs = new Specificatrion(){
        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Father> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, final CriteriaBuilder cb){
             Root<Child> childRoot = query.from(Child.class);
             Path<?> path = childRoot.get(Child_.school.name);
             Predicate pred = exp.in("School Name");
             return cb.and(pred);
         }
}
```

Can some one help me on this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do have a reverse relationship in your Child back to the Father, so the child can bridge between the school and the father.

Something like this will work :

```
@Entity
public class Father {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "father", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Child> childs = new HashSet<>();


@Entity
public class Child {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Father father;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private School school;
```

Then in your FatherRepository :

```
@Query("select father from Child child join child.father father join child.school school where school.name=:school")
List<Father> findBySchool(@Param("school") String school);
```

Comment: Hi Essex,
I'd like to use Specifications.
Will try to change and see what happens,
Thanks!

Comment: You can use Specifications but I don't think you can have the hierachy as you have set in your question.  Happy to be proved wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I know its late. But may help someone.

I have entity InwardInventory having list of child entity  InwardOutwardList again having list of child Product. So to filter InwardInventories that have a specific product.

```
Specification<InwardInventory> finalSpec = null;

finalSpec = specbldr.whereChildFieldListContains(
                InwardInventory_.INWARD_OUTWARD_LIST,InwardOutwardList_.PRODUCT,Product_.PRODUCT_NAME,productNames));
```

Generic Definition for specbldr.whereChildFieldListContains method

```
public Specification<T> whereChildFieldListContains(String childTableName, String gcTable,String fieldName, List<String> names) 
    {
        Specification<T> finalSpec = null;
        for(String name:names)
        {
            Specification<T> internalSpec = (Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb)
                -> cb.like(root.join(childTableName).join(gcTable).get(fieldName), "%"+name+"%" );
                finalSpec  = specOrCondition(finalSpec,internalSpec);
        }
        return finalSpec;
    }
```

Let me know if you need further help